# Wrap all numerics in JSON with quotes

Tags: shell, json, jq

There are JSON data which contains some numeric values. How to convert all numerics to strings? (wrap with quotes)

Example:

```
{
        "id":1,
        "customer":"user",
        "plate":"BMT-216-A",
        "country":"GB",
        "amount":1000,
        "pndNumber":20000,
        "zoneNumber":4
}
```

should become

```
{
        "id":"1",
        "customer":"user",
        "plate":"BMT-216-A",
        "country":"GB",
        "amount":"1000",
        "pndNumber":"20000",
        "zoneNumber":"4"
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$ jq 'map_values(tostring)' file.json
{
  "id": "1",
  "customer": "user",
  "plate": "BMT-216-A",
  "country": "GB",
  "amount": "1000",
  "pndNumber": "20000",
  "zoneNumber": "4"
}
```

Redirect to a new file and then move that to the original filename.

For a more thorough conversion of numbers in non-flat structures into strings, consider

```
jq '(..|select(type == "number")) |= tostring' file.json
```

This would examine every value recursively in the given document, and select the ones that are numbers. The selected values are then converted into strings. It would also, strictly speaking, look at the keys, but since these can't be plain numbers in JSON, no key would be selected.

Example:

```
$ jq . file.json
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1
  },
  "b": null,
  "c": [
    1,
    2,
    "hello",
    4
  ]
}
```

```
$ jq '(..|select(type == "number")) |= tostring' file.json
{
  "a": {
    "b": "1"
  },
  "b": null,
  "c": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "hello",
    "4"
  ]
}
```

To additionally quote the `null`, change the `select()` to

```
select(type == "number" or type == "null")
```

Answer (score 8):

here's an easy solution based on **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)** unix utility:

```
bash $ jtc -w'<.*>D:' -eu echo '"{}"' \; file.json
{
   "amount": "1000",
   "country": "GB",
   "customer": "user",
   "id": "1",
   "plate": "BMT-216-A",
   "pndNumber": "20000",
   "zoneNumber": "4"
}
bash $
```

if you like to apply changes right into the json file, use the `-f` switch, like this:

```
bash $ jtc -f -w'<.*>D:' -eu echo '"{}"' \; file.json
```

The proposed solution will work correctly with an arbitrary structured jsons, e.g.:

```
bash $ jtc -w'<.*>D:' -eu echo '"{}"' \; file.json
{
   "amount": "1000",
   "country": "GB",
   "customer": "user",
   "id": "1",
   "plate": "BMT-216-A",
   "pndNumber": "20000",
   "sub": {
      "subvalue": "123"
   },
   "zoneNumber": "4"
}
bash $
```

- if you like to quote null values, just throw in a walk-path `-w'<>n:'`
- if you like to quote boolean values, throw in a walk-path `-w'<any>b:'`

Also, the reverse task (unquote all the numerics) is easily achieved in the similar way: say, `file.json` is already "enquoted", to unquote all the numerics:

```
bash $ jtc -w'<^\d+$>R:' -eu echo {-} \; file.json
{
   "amount": 1000,
   "country": "GB",
   "customer": "user",
   "id": 1,
   "plate": "BMT-216-A",
   "pndNumber": 20000,
   "zoneNumber": 4
}
bash $
```

**UPDATE**: the latest version of `jtc` implements now templates and namespaces. With that no invocation of external shell is required:

```
bash $ jtc -w'<.*>D:' -u'<.*>D:<val>v' -T'"{val}"' file.json
{
   "amount": "1000",
   "country": "GB",
   "customer": "user",
   "id": "1",
   "plate": "BMT-216-A",
   "pndNumber": "20000",
   "zoneNumber": "4"
}
```

`jtc` user guide: https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -pe 's/("(?:\\.|[^"])*")|[^\s[\]{}:,"]+/$1||qq("$&")/ge' file.json
```

Would quote anything that is not quoted and is not `[]{}:,whitespace`, so would quote numbers, `true`, `false` and `null`.

```
perl -pe 's/("(?:\\.|[^"])*")|-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?/$1||qq("$&")/ge'
```

Would specifically quote what matches the specification of a json number and that is not already inside quotes.

Those do an exact tokenising based on the JSON specification, it's not an approximation.

Answer (score -1):

I tried with below method and it worked fine.

I pipelined 2 times tried up to my level to reduce it

Command:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,\},\?$/"&/g' filename |
sed '/[0-9]\{1,\}$/s/[0-9]\{1,\}/&"/g'|
sed '/[0-9]\{1,\},$/s/,$/"&/g`'
```

Output:

```
 {
        "id":"1",
        "customer":"user",
        "plate":"BMT-216-A",
        "country":"GB",
        "amount":"1000",
        "pndNumber":"20000",
        "zoneNumber":"4"
}
```

Comment: @Kusalananda corrected the code

Comment: why do you use `\{1,\},`? To test whether an element appears one or more times use `+`. And this won't work for numbers like -123, 0xab, 0o12, 0b1011, 1e23 or 1.2e3...

Comment: @phuclv `\{1,\}` is the BRE equivalent of ERE `+`. Some `sed` implementations support `\+` as an extension or a `-E` or `-r` option to enable EREs but that's not portable. `\?` is another non-portable extension though whose standard equivalent is `\{0,1\}`

Comment: @phuclv you wouldn't find unquoted 0xab 0o12 0b1011 numbers in a valid JSON file.